# After the width or height of a canvas element changed, the font for its 2d context set to default value

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
var cvs = Damoo.dom.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = f.value;
cvs.width = ctx.measureText("text").width;
cvs.height = f.size * 1.2;
//now the font value set to default value, you must reset it
ctx.font = f.value;
```

So anyone knows is this a bug or by design?
The environment is latest Chrome

When I try save and restore, the code is

```
var cvs = Damoo.dom.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = f.value;
cvs.save();
cvs.width = ctx.measureText("text").width;
cvs.height = f.size * 1.2;
//now the font value set to default value, you must reset it
//ctx.font = f.value;
cvs.restore();
```

Comment: In short, it is by design, the canvas context will reset when you change its size. If you want to keep things like the font after changing the size, you can use [`save() restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will do this

Comment: After some try I'm guess that save() and restore() cannot solve this

Comment: I suggest you update your question with the code your tried, it would be easier to help you that way.

Comment: would not be better to make an answer? the question has been answered but just in comments, wouldn't it be more user friendly to make an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

ctx.save() and ctx.restore() ignore the font value. Instead of restore, reset your font *(They probably forgot to include it because any other explanation is pointless.)*

Solution:

```
ctx.font = f.value;
...measureText and adjust canvas size
ctx.font = f.value;
```

Comment: it's not that it's ignored, it's that when you change the width or height of the <canvas>, every properties of the context are reset, and this includes the list of saved states. So when you call `restore()` after that, there is no state to restore anymore.